# Trying to get a text box defined value to result in a certain number of returned values

Tags: javascript, html, while-loop

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function printMultiples() {
        var num = parseFloat(document.getElementById("num").value);
        var Multiples = 1;
        var MultiplesDiv = document.getElementByid("Multiples");
        MultiplesDiv.innerHTML = "";
        var multipleCount:document.getElementByid("multipleCount");
        while (num = 0; n < multipleCount; n++)
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div>
      <h3>
        Print <input type="text" id="multipleCount" value="10" /> multiples of
        <input type="text" id="factor" value="5" /> <br /><br />
        <input
          type="button"
          size="10"
          value="Calculate"
          onclick="printMultiples();"
        />
      </h3>
    </div>

    <div id="multipleOutput"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Ok so the goal here is to make it so that when I enter a value into the textboxes of *multipleCount* and *value*, that it takes the value box and then continues to multiply it by 2 for a number of times. The amount of times is specified by the *multipleCount*. The problem I am having is I am unsure as to how to continue from this point forward. I am relatively new to coding and not sure how to finish this segment off. I already have the portion so that it will clear the values and replace them with the new ones every time I press the button, now I just need it to actually output the values.

Comment: Can you please elaborate the logic a bit more? also where is the "value" textbox?

Comment: How exactly do you want the result to be displayed then?